# Select xml node by its attribute value in Jenkins groovy

Tags: xml, jenkins, groovy

I have the following XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<testsuites>
  <testsuite name="xray" tests="2" failure="0" timestamp="2023-07-07T05:25:33.339Z" skipped="0" failure-evaluating="0">
    <testcase name="SPT-4323" classname="testim.io.test" time="52.597" ownedBy="Staysure Automation" ownerEmail="automationteam@staysure.co.uk">
    </testcase>
    <testcase name="SPT-4331" classname="testim.io.test" time="20.823" ownedBy="Automation Team" ownerEmail="nipunam@intervest.lk">
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

I need to select the node `<testcase name="SPT-4323"` to append another node as a child.
I've tried following ways and both says "`groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChildren.find`"

xml.testsuite.find{it.@name == 'SPT-4323'}.appendNode( fragmentToAdd )
xml.testsuite.testcase.find{it.@name == 'SPT-4323'}.appendNode( fragmentToAdd )

Following is the full Jenkins pipeline stage

```
stage('Update_XML') {
        try{
            def File = readFile "${env.WORKSPACE}/testim-tests-report.xml"
            echo "${File}"
            def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(File)
            def xrayIDs = xml.testsuite.testcase.collect { it.@name }
            
            echo "Xray IDs are ${xrayIDs}"
                            
            def toadd = '''<properties>
                            <property name="test_key" value="SPT-4323" />
                        </properties>'''
            
            fragmentToAdd = new XmlSlurper( false, true ).parseText( toadd )

            xml.testsuite.find{it.@name == 'SPT-4323'}.appendNode( fragmentToAdd )
            
            String outxml = groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize( xml )
            echo "Output XML ${outxml}"
            
            
        } catch(Exception) {
            build_status = false
            echo Exception.toString()
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I could able to sort the issue by adding `'**'` before the find.

```
def node = xml.testsuite.'**'.find { it.@name == 'SPT-4323' }
node.appendNode ( fragmentToAdd )
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Running this code in groovyConsole (Groovy 3) works for me:

```
def file = new File("testim-tests-report.xml")
def parsed = new XmlSlurper().parseText(file.text)

println XmlUtil.serialize(parsed)

def toAdd = '<newnode>Testing</newnode>'
def fragToAdd = new XmlSlurper().parseText(toAdd)
parsed.testsuite.testcase.find {
    it.@name == 'SPT-4323'
}.appendNode(fragToAdd)

println XmlUtil.serialize(parsed)
```